# Scalable Middleware with Scheduled Tasks?

Tags: architecture, scheduled-tasks, middleware

We are designing a Middleware that accepts requests from a Client. This Middleware should be scalable and be behind a load-balancer.

Our Middleware's main job is to process the request and forward it external servers for additional processing.

One thing we need to consider is **scheduled processing**; for example, a specific request can be scheduled to be forwarded *ONLY* at a specific time in the future (ex. after 3 hours).

Because of this, it introduces need to **Persist Scheduled Jobs**; it is needed to handle scenario where 1 server goes down, then other servers can still pick it up.

We have considered this approach:

1. Use DB storage to persist Scheduled Jobs
2. Middleware has background job periodically to query DB if there are any pending Jobs that needs to be sent
3. Use some kind of DB concurrency to handle multiple Middleware instances possible looking at same scheduled jobs

However, I am thinking that this design might not be optimal? Particularly, in the recurring background job because it might seem that some processing is wasted (ex. if there is  always contention of data in DB).

**Edit: Another alternative solution**

1. Middleware receives scheduled request
2. Middleware creates / pushes scheduled request to a message queue (with time delay)
3. Separate function hosted (ex. Azure Functions) receive from Message Queue
4. Function processes the scheduled request

It seems with this approach, it is more scalable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [temporal.io](https://temporal.io/) for this. Here is how the implementation of your business logic will look like using the Java SDK (Go, PHP, Ruby are also supported):

```java
    public void execute(Request r) {
      Workflow.sleep(Duration.ofHours(3));
      activities.forwardRequest(r);
    }
```

Temporal preserves the complete state of the function. Thus even in the presence of process and other infrastructure failures the code is guaranteed to execute. So it is OK to sleep for any period of time synchronously (even months).

Not directly related to the question, but I still think that it is worth mentioning that Temporal is already a middleware that has many more features than the one you are trying to implement. So I believe you don't really need to implement your own :). I would recommend designing your application to use the Temporal SDKs directly.